# Continuous expansion of an holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to prove that $(z-1)e^ \frac {z+1}{z-1}$ is holomorphic in the open unit disk and can be expanded continuously in the closed unit disk.

Can you help with a hint or solution?

Comment: What happens when $z\to1$?

Comment: Can you find $\lim \limits_{z\to1}\left((z-1)\exp\left(\dfrac{z+1}{z-1}\right)\right)$?

Comment: Nope, I'm stuck at that point.

Comment: I can't seem to get around the 0 times infinity obstacle

Comment: Can't you rewrite that so it yields $\infty/\infty$ and then apply L'hopital?

Comment: I don't think L'hospital works that way in complex functions. If it was real then the limit goes to infinity. But in the complex plane I believe this should go to zero. That's where I am confused

Comment: Just note that the function has only one pole on the boundaries!

Comment: I think if you take real values coming from the left of $1$ it goes to $0$ but if you take real values coming from the right of $1$ it goes to $\infty$. My previous suggestion was bogus anyway, doing L'H once just leads you to doing it again and again....

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal I noticed that, but it doesn't ring any bells. Can you reveal some more? Also I might not be allowed to use singularities because we haven't talked about that in the class yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only point to worry about is $z=1$; at every other point of $\mathbb{C}$ the function is analytic.

Observe that the transformation $w=(z+1)/(z-1)$ maps the unit disk to the half-plane $\operatorname{Re}w<0$. In this half-plane the exponential function is bounded. And if you multiply a bounded function by $(z-1)$, the product is sure to have a limit as $z\to 1$.

Comment: Thank you. I had trouble explaining why it goes to zero. The funny thing is I made these observations but failed to see the connection! Thanks